# Microsoft DMA SQLServer 2008 R2 to Azure SQL - Cross DB References

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, azure

We currently have a server that houses our SQLServer 2008 R2 instance, and we may be migrating to Azure SQL. To prepare, I'm using Microsoft's Data Migration Assistant so that we can ensure that there won't be any issues in the migration.

I took care of the 'migration blockers' under the Compatibility Issues section. However, under the SQL Server feature parity section, it states that nearly all of the databases have Cross-Database references. These are not supported by Azure SQL. Of course, the DMA doesn't provide any specifics what-so-ever regarding what those references are.

I tried finding them on my own using the query:

```
SELECT
  DB_NAME() as referencing_database_name,
  OBJECT_NAME (referencing_id) as referencing_entity_name,
  ISNULL(referenced_schema_name,'dbo') as referenced_schema_name,
  referenced_entity_name,
  ao.type_desc as referenced_entity_type,
  ISNULL(referenced_database_name,DB_NAME()) as referenced_database_name
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies sed
  JOIN sys.all_objects ao
    ON sed.referenced_entity_name = ao.name
```

However, I don't see anything listed that actually references another database. Am I misunderstanding a key concept, here? Can anyone shed some light on this?